# deleting only one row when there are duplicates

Tags: php, mysql

Regarding this line

```
  database::query("DELETE FROM bo WHERE name='{$this->_protected_arr[a1]}' AND email='$_SESSION[email]'");
```

How can I update it so that it only deletes one row instead of all of them.

Also, the syntax looks off, is there any way not to use the {}.

Also, normally PHP calls warnings if ther are no apostrohpes in associative array but it does not pick it up in this case.  So this seems wrong as well.

So this is actually 3 questions.

Comment: Which row do you want it to delete?

Comment: Pro hint: Always escape your data in SQL statements, even if they're in variables that you're reasonably sure contain safe data (things change). Better yet, abandon string concatenation altogether and use parameterized queries instead (PDO).

Comment: `"{$this->_protected_arr[a1]}"` is wrong (will issue `Use of undefined constant a1`. Correct would be: `"{$this->_protected_arr['a1']}"`

Comment: it works on my version of PHP.  I copied it directly from working code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I update it so that it only deletes one row instead of all of them.

Use a `LIMIT 1` clause at the end of the query.

> the syntax looks off

It's correct. It's what PHP calls the "complex (curly) syntax" for variable parsing in strings:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex

You can of course use string concatenation there if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `LIMIT 1`. The question is which row will be caught in `LIMIT 1` selection :)

The best case scenario is that your **database::query** supports placeholders.

Concerning curly brakets, just add apostrophes to the array key

```
   database::query("DELETE FROM bo WHERE name='{$this->_protected_arr['a1']}' AND email='{$_SESSION['email']}'");
```

If you don't wanna use curly brakets, then just concatenate strings like `"DELETE ...".$this->property." AND ..."`.

Answer (score 0):

```
database::query("DELETE FROM bo WHERE name='{$this->_protected_arr[a1]}' AND email='$_SESSION[email]' LIMIT 1");
```

Answer (score 0):

As everyone else suggested, adding a LIMIT 1 to the end of your query will make it so that only one row is deleted. However, given you're using static classes here, I'm guessing you know enough to understand why everything in a database should have its own unique identifier and I'm curious why you aren't using that as part of your criteria for determining what you delete? Or there should at least be some other comparison you can do, like running a select statement that pulls all the rows and then loops over the results, setting them to a multidimensional array where you can then compare the column values for the multiple rows and use that comparison to decide which row to keep. If you're getting multiple entries maybe look into preventing users from double-clicking by using jquery to hide the button or gray it out as soon as it's been clicked. Just some thoughts...